# Event handling in js

Tags: javascript, dhtml

i have a div

```
<div id="mainDiv" onclick="devide(this.id, event);" style="z-index:1;position:relative; width:400px; height:400px; border:1px red solid;"></div>
```

on its click i append to more divs to it and want the same thing to happen to them, means on there click 2 more divs shud b added to them

on click on mainDiv
mainDiv
   -mainDiv0
   -mainDiv1

on click on mainDiv0
mainDiv
   -mainDiv0
      -mainDiv00
      -mainDiv01
   -mainDiv1

i guess i was able to clear the things

i used following js

```
function devide(id, evt){
    alert(id);
    var divElement = document.getElementById(id);
    if(typeof(divElement) != "undefined" && divElement!=null){
        captureMousePosition(evt);
        if(splitVertical==1)
            verticalSplit(divElement);
        else
            horizontalSplit(divElement);
    }
}

function verticalSplit(divElement){
    divElement.style.border = "0px red dashed";
//  divElement.removeAttribute("onclick");
    var width = ((divElement.offsetWidth-(xMousePos-LEFT_MARGIN))/divElement.offsetWidth)*100;
    var newDiv1 = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv1.setAttribute("id", divElement.id+"0");
//  newDiv1.onclick = "devide('"+divElement.id+"0', event);";
    newDiv1.style.width = (100-width)+"%";
    newDiv1.style.height = "100%";
    newDiv1.style.float = "left";
    newDiv1.style.border = "1px red dashed";
    newDiv1.style.zIndex = divElement.style.zIndex+1;
    var newDiv2 = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv2.setAttribute("id", divElement.id+"1");
    newDiv2.style.width = width+"%";
    newDiv2.style.height = "100%";
    newDiv2.style.float = "left";
    newDiv2.style.border = "1px red dashed";
    newDiv2.style.zIndex = divElement.style.zIndex+1;
    divElement.appendChild(newDiv1);
    divElement.appendChild(newDiv2);
    newDiv1.addEventListener("click",devide(divElement.id+"0", event),true);
    newDiv2.addEventListener("click",devide(divElement.id+"1", event),true);
}
```

but this is recursively calling devide function for the first encountered element say mainDiv0,mainDiv00,mainDiv000.... and so on

please help me with this

Comment: are u using any lib like Jquery, mootools!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The situation you are describing is called [event bubbling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html).

The W3C model says you can call `.stopPropagation()` on the event. IE might need `window.event.cancelBubble`

To do [unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) with your code try:

**HTML**

```
<div id="mainDiv"></div>
```

**JS**

```
function devide(evt){
    var divElement = document.getElementById(this.id);// this.id !
    if(typeof(divElement) != "undefined" && divElement!=null){
        captureMousePosition(evt);
        if(splitVertical==1)
            verticalSplit(divElement);
        else
            horizontalSplit(divElement);
    }
}

document.getElementById('mainDiv').onclick=devide; // notice it's just the function name
```

Comment: whats the best suggested way to add event using javascript??? addeventListner is not working on FF

Comment: `addEventListener` is not working? Did you write it with an uppercase E? I'd honestly recommend using http://jquery.com/ it will ease your way into more complex things you can do with JS.

Comment: i am using javascript cannot include jQuery though even i wish to learn it.. project constraint

Comment: 'newDiv1.addEventListener("click",devide(divElement.id+"0", event),true);'

Comment: I think that doing it like that you actually call the function devide. see my update.

Comment: document.getElementById('mainDiv')=devide; 

or 


document.getElementById('mainDiv').onclick=devide;

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the lines:

```
var divElement = document.getElementById(id);
if(typeof(divElement) != "undefined" && divElement!=null){
```

*typeof* is an operator, not a function, so it doesn't need to be followed by a grouping operator ().

More importantly, the first part of the test is unnecessary and the second part can be reduced to:

```
if (divElement) {
```

If a *document* object doesn't exist, or does not support *getElementById* then the first line will result in a script error and stop execution. If the first line executes successfully, then *divElement* will either be a reference to a DOM element or *null* (per the W3C DOM Core specification).

Given the above, if *divElement != null* returns true, then *typeof divElement != 'undefined'* must return true (since *divElement* can't be undefined and even if it was, *undefined == null*), and vice versa, so it is redundant. If an explicit test is required (and it rarely is), then:

```
if (divElement !== null) {
```

should be used.